# Shiny: How to create a table/like user input

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to create a user input in the form of a table in shiny. The code below would create the skeleton table:

```
age <- c('00-10' , '11-20' , '>21')
male <- c(NA , NA , NA)
female <- c(NA , NA , NA)

input_table <- data.frame(age , male , female)
```

I would like the user to see this table and be able to enter quantities for the corresponding age and gender.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/22272571/602276 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/19706320/602276